# Mysql select query using REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using a regulear expression im mysql like this

```
select * from table1 where
table1.name
REGEXP '[[:<:]]1.1[[:>:]]'
```

The query shows results, whose name field has value 1.1.1 also. Like this

```
pk  name
5   1.1
6   1.1.1
```

but I need to match only 1.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table1 where
table1.name
REGEXP '^1.1$'
```

makes sure that only `1.1` is allowed (but also `1X1` or `111` because the dot matches any character - if you want to match a literal dot, use `^1\.1$`).

Of course, now there's the question why you'd want to use a regex at all since it's just a literal string you're matching, not a variable pattern.

Your regex failed because you were using start-/end-of-word anchors that match between alphanumeric characters and non-alphanumerics (or start/end of string), and since `[[:>:]]` matches between `1` and `.`, the regex matched `1.1.1` at least partially.